# Transpiled circuit with optimization level 3 error in IBMbackend.run() method. (Key Error 16, 22)

Tags: programming, quantum-circuit

when I try to use the method backend.run() with a transpiled circuit with optimization level 1-3 an error occurs.

[image]

My code:

[image: My Code]

When I don't specify any optimization level it works. The backend.name is ibm_osaka

Should I specify more parameters in one of the two methods?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same problem, it seems to be a problem with the mapping between virtual qubits and physical qubits in the quantum computer.

I have fixed the issue by specifying the initial layout in the transpile function.

[image]